# moving quantities from outside to inside an integral (Apostol Th 4.2)

Tags: integration

In Apostol's Theorem 4.2 derivation, he moved a quantity from outside an integral into an integral (see image below).

The $A(x)$ is defined as $\sum_{n\leq x}a(n)$ where $a(n)$ is an arithmetic function.

**Question:** The integral is from $n$ to $n+1$ inclusive of the endpoints. However the value of $A(n)$ changes inside the integral as $A(n+1)=A(n)+a(n+1)$. Why is this a valid algebraic manipulation?

[image]

Comment: For $n \le t < n+1$ we have $A(t) = A(n)$ ??

Comment: @GEdgar but at the top end of the interval of integration $A(t)=A(n+1)\neq A(n)$. Why can we ignore the value of $A(t)$ at $t=n+1$?

Comment: Change an integrand in one point, the integral is unchanged.

Comment: @GEdgar - so the integral of $sin(x)$ in an interval is the same as $sin(x)+\sum_{n} \delta(x-x_n)$ which adds singular spikes of infinitesimal width? I am not an expert, and yes this does make intuitive sense as the area contributed is zero.

Comment: I checked the book, Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory (he's written more than one book, you know - it's a good idea to  be as complete as you can in your references). You have misread the definition of $A(x)$. The definition in the text (p. 77) is indeed $A(x) = \sum_{n\le x} a_n$ - which is NOT what you have written above. The explanation given below is correct with the text's definition - but not with yours.

Comment: As for your question/comment with what I take to be the usual $\delta$ function... The $\delta$ function  is NOT a function, strictly speaking. It's a distribution.... not the best choice to use for clearing up misconceptions about integration. (cont)

Comment: (cont) But yes, that a function jumps (but is finite) at the end point does not change the value of the integration. To see why this is, try $f(x)=0$, except for $f(1)=1$. To evaluate/estimate $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$, draw some rectangles, a la Riemann sum, with the length of the base(s) going to $0$. The sum of the areas goes to $0$ (converging to the value of the integral!). There are of course much more general results. Best wishes, and good luck with Apostol!

Comment: thanks @peterag - I have edited the question based on your correction. If you'd like to add this as an answer, I'd be very happy to mark is as "solved"

Comment: don't worry about it! best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $[n,n+1]$, you have$$A(t)=\begin{cases}A(n)&\text{ if }t\in[n,n+1)\\A(n+1)&\text{ if }t=n+1,\end{cases}$$and therefore\begin{align}\int_n^{n+1}A(t)f'(t)\,\mathrm dt&=\int_n^{n+1}A(n)f'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=A(n)\int_n^{n+1}f'(t)\,\mathrm dt.\end{align}Concerning the first equality, I've used the fact that, if $f,g\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ are integrable and $f(x)\ne g(x)$ for finitely many $x$'s only, then$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Hi Jose, why can we ignore the value of $A(t)$ at $t=n+1$, the upper limit of integration?

Comment: Because when $f,g\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ are integrable and $f(x)\ne g(x)$ only for a finite number of $x$'s, then $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Hi Jose -  this last comment has addressed the very issue. If you'd like to add it to your "answer" I'll click the "solved" button.

Comment: @Tariq It's done.